# When is 0.5 is added and substraced to the normal probability approximated the binomial probability?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

[image]

I dont understand why "0.5" is added. I saw sometimes 0.5 is added and sometimes it is reduced. Can I know when to add or substract  0.5 ?

Comment: To make up for the fact that boxes with integer centers don't fit exactly under the normal curve.

Comment: There are explanations all over the internet.  Here's one:  https://youtu.be/CCqWkJ_pqNU?t=424

Comment: The binomial distribution is discrete but you're approximating it with a continuous normal distribution, and this makes the approximation significantly better when $n$ is kind of small. As $n$ gets larger, this correction matters less and less.

Comment: Another explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction

Comment: If $X$ and $x$ are integers then $P(X\le x)=P(X\lt x+1)$ which makes deciding what normal approximation to use more difficult.  This uses $P(X\le x + \frac12) = P(X\lt x + \frac12)$ for the approximation